# JQuery DatePicker date format query

Tags: jquery

I have recently managed to get the JQuery Datepicker widget integrated into a web site i am building for a client.

Now what i need to do to finish this particular task off is change the date format from mm-dd-yy to dd-mm-yy

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

based on the above info and the code i am currently using, shown below, how would i achieve this??

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
});


<input class="w-input input hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Expected Moving Date" name="datepicker" data-name="datepicker" required="required">
```

thank you

Comment: _"how would i achieve this??"_ Um, use the option you linked to??

Comment: You can also change it the `regional` settings in the jquery-ui file `dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"`

Comment: actually i need to ask 1 more question. Since my site uses multiple forms, and i have this particular input field used on each of the forms, what do i do in this case? since i cant use the same id 'datepicker' for each of the other input fields. Is it possible to do something like; $( "#datepicker", "#datepicker2", "#datepicker3" ).datepicker etc....is this possible (im not a programmer btw) ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jquery ready 2 times. Your code should be like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" 
    });
});
```

Full example with changed date format to "dd-mm-yy" http://jsfiddle.net/63wrvtxn/1/

If you want to add datepicker to multiple input field you can add a class datepicker istead of the id http://jsfiddle.net/63wrvtxn/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you down voting? :)

Comment: @jurgemaister If you look at his code he is calling it twice $( document ).ready(function() {
$(function() { . $(function() { ... }); is jQuery short-hand for $(document).ready(function() { ... }); . So you are wrong :) Read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: actually i need to ask 1 more question.  Since my site uses multiple forms, and i have this particular input field used on each of the forms, what do i do in this case?

since i cant use the same id 'datepicker' for each of the other input fields. Is it possible to do something like;

$( "#datepicker", "#datepicker2", "#datepicker3" ).datepicker

etc....is this possible (im not a programmer btw)   ???

Comment: I have updated the answer to include multiple datepickers to one page. If this answers your question please accept the answer :)